# Jenkins configuration page takes a very long time to load

Tags: jenkins

I am running the latest Jenkins LTS - 2.121.1. Performance is generally quite good, however, whenever I try to open the configuration page (Manage Jenkins --> Configure system), it takes an extremely long time for the page to load (a good minute or so).

The same issue is present whenever I attempt to save any configuration changes.

I'm assuming this is due to a plugin update or bad config somewhere, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the problem. Note that it did not start occurring after a Jenkins upgrade - i'm not exactly sure when / what caused the issue to occur, as I am taking ownership of a cluster of Jenkins masters. This is one of the issues I am trying to solve.

Things I have ruled out so far:
 - Not enough memory, cpu 
 - Changing the JVM memory settings 
 - Some browser caching issue - still present in incognito mode

I tried creating a new Jenkins instance and copying in the Jenkins home from the problematic one, inc plugins, but iI haven't been able to get it to a state where I can reproduce the issue cleanly.

I've tried out a few solutions online (hence some of the points above) but with little success. Another suggestion was to capture a thread dump and analyse, when the hang is occurring, which I have included below.

I'd imagine that if I could read this stack trace correctly, it might indicate what plugin / component is hanging the UI, but afraid I don't have much experience in this area.

If anyone has experienced this in the past or any suggestions, I'd welcome your input. Thread dump below.

```
Handling GET /configure from 10.26.132.164 : RequestHandlerThread[#6] Jenkins/configure.jelly
"Handling GET /configure from 10.26.132.164 : RequestHandlerThread[#6] Jenkins/configure.jelly" Id=27 Group=main RUNNABLE
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:819)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1282)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:1249)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:215)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:569)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.getResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:447)
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.getViewPage(Descriptor.java:836)
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.getGlobalConfigPage(Descriptor.java:814)
    at hudson.Functions.getSortedDescriptorsForGlobalConfig(Functions.java:1003)
    at hudson.Functions.getSortedDescriptorsForGlobalConfigUnclassified(Functions.java:1037)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:258)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:83)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:57)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReferenceExpression.value(ASTReferenceExpression.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.ExpressionImpl.evaluate(ExpressionImpl.java:80)
    at hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression.evaluate(ExpressionFactory2.java:74)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.expression.ExpressionSupport.evaluateRecurse(ExpressionSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.expression.ExpressionSupport.evaluateAsIterator(ExpressionSupport.java:94)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet$1.dispatch(JellyFacet.java:97)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:225)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.support.slowrequest.SlowRequestFilter.doFilter(SlowRequestFilter.java:37)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:61)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.plugins.audit_trail.AuditTrailFilter.doFilter(AuditTrailFilter.java:92)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Number of locked synchronizers = 1
    - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@5db6b9cd
```